# Is there a possibility to limit the jQuery background image scroll?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a jQuery Script for changing the `background-position` of a background-image while scrolling down the page.

The issue is that I want to change the `background-position` until the image arrives at `background-position` "bottom" because otherwise the `background-image` ends and the overflow is visible.

```js
jQuery(window).bind("load resize scroll", function(e) {
  var y = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  
  jQuery(".hero").filter(function() {
    return jQuery(this).offset().top < (y + jQuery(window).height()) &&
      jQuery(this).offset().top + jQuery(this).height() > y;
  }).css('background-position', '0px ' + parseInt(-y / 10) + 'px');
});
```

Comment: You could base the image offset on the percentage of the screen scrolled, rather than a direct: X pixels scrolled = Y background image pixels moved.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, do you have a particular code solution for that? Thanks